# How to get data from second stream by first?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have tried to get data from BehSubject `this.visible$` only in case when `this.redraw$` happends.

It works, but if the `this.visible$` is changed somewhere the prev stream again works. How to avoid it?

```
this.redraw$.pipe(mergeMap(() => this.visible$)).subscribe((userfavourite: UserFavourite[]) => {}
```

As solution I can do this:

```
this.redraw$.subcribe(() => {
   this.visible$.subscribe((userfavourite: UserFavourite[]) => {}
});
```

Comment: Did not understand what do you mean by `It works, but if the this.visible$ is changed somewhere the prev stream again works.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```ts
this.redraw$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.visible$),
  map(([_,v]) => v)
).subscribe(visible => {
  /* Do Something */
});
```